# Central Limit Theorem for Dependent Non-Identical Random Variables.

Tags: probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, normal-distribution, probability-limit-theorems

If $X_{(1)}, X_{(2)},\ldots$ are mutually dependent as in the case of ordered statistics and we need to find the sum $S_N$ of all $X_{(i)}$ like  $\sum_{i=1}^{N\to \infty} X_{(i)}$.

How do we apply the CLT in this case?

I've been searching around but all I could find is the CLT for sum of I.I.D. random variables. I haven't found anything for cases when the R.V.s are Non-I.I.D.

I hope my question is clear enough. If not, please be gentle.

Comment: Well, to decide that random variables are not necessarily independent and not necessarily identically distributed is to say that they can be anything at all. Then why CLT should hold? Either you are after a specific situation, then describe it precisely, or this is NARQ.

Comment: You can't say anything in the absence of assumptions. What kind of cases are you interested in?

Comment: If $X_{(1)},\ldots,X_{(n)}$ are the order statistics from an i.i.d. sample $X_1,\ldots,X_n$, then their sum is the same as the sum of the latter i.i.d. random variables, so CLT would apply.  Without _some_ assumptions, the conclusion of CLT won't hold.  That there are various assumptions other than "i.i.d." under which the conclusion must hold is known, but I'm not prepared to give an account of those right now.

Comment: I appreciate your comments and time. @QiaochuYuan:
I suppose assumptions in this context means what I can infer about the Mean and Variance of $X_{(i)}$. We can say that $X_{(i)}$ has a finite mean and finite variance. That is,

$E[X_i]= \mu < \infty$ $\forall$ i $\in N$

$Var[X_i]= \sigma < \infty$ $\forall$ i $\in N$ and $\sigma^2> 0$

Please if this is not what you mean, I'd look at it again and try to give some feedback. Thanks